# jquery set Data Type and Content Type in load method

Tags: jquery

```
segment.load(action_path + '?' + $( this ).serialize());
```

Above is my code I would like to set the below parameter in request from load method.

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8,ISO-8859-6;'dataType:'html'
```

So that I can accept arabic characters properly rendered in IE.

I can't use $.ajax() method because the segment is an object and in response I am getting html
content.

Help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) function to specifiy the setting of your ajax call.

Comment: thanks let me test it with setting $.ajaxSetup({
       global: false,
       contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8,ISO-8859-6;',
       dataType:'html'
    });

Comment: I have tried setting up $.ajaxSetup() method just above my $.load() method. but my resulting page text box is not understanding arabic charecters it shows ????? specially in all version of IE. please help

Comment: @MehulChauhan, if my suggestion worked, accepts this answer. and for your second problem please create a new question. Someone will answer it if you do it. Many people wont be reading comments.